# MS Access 2010: Linking to SharePoint list with Multiple Content Types -Read-Only

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010

When linking to a SharePoint 2010 list which has multiple content types, the [Content Type] field in MS Access is read-only.  This makes it impossible to add records targeted toward a specific content type from within MS Access, as only the default content type is pre-populated with a new record.

There has got to be a way...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a sharepoint programmer but I suspect that the value is set through an object not a simple assignment, something like (and this is just a guess)

```
dim myContentType as sharepoint.contenttype
set myContentType = new sharepoint.contentType
myContentType.value = "content"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I was hoping I wouldn't have to attack it from code, but rather just be able to use the normal MS Access queries to append & update rows in the linked SHarePoint list. After all, it works perfectly that way for any lists with a single content type. Odd that Microsoft hasn't addressed this, or even have an FAQ about it.  I'll look into a code solution, although I don't know of a SharePoint object model exposed in MS Access.  Do you by chance?  Thanks again.

Comment: You could consider using an Attachment column. Access supports these and this allows various document types etc. to be saved in the one row. Unfortunately, I not played with content types.

Comment: Albert:  Thanks for the reply, but I'm referring to content types, not document types.